# JavaFx TableView error

Tags: javafx, tableview

I am new to JavaFX. I am working with TableView and trying to put data entered by the user from the fields Username and Password into the table. Its just a testing program. I am getting the error below.

```
SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass Failed to load skin 'StringProperty [bean: TableRow[id=null, styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell], name: skinClassName, value: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin]' for control TableRow[id=null, styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures
    at javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.recreateCells(TableRowSkin.java:224)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Control.java:992)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.access$500(Control.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.invalidated(Control.java:920)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:161)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(StyleableStringProperty.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.set(Control.java:912)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:902)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7415)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1102)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1598)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1500)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1523)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow$3.call(VirtualFlow.java:478)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow$3.call(VirtualFlow.java:476)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.PositionMapper.computeViewportOffset(PositionMapper.java:143)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1001)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1018)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1028)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.layoutDirtyRoots(Scene.java:513)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:484)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$3900(Scene.java:169)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2199)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:460)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(QuantumToolkit.java:329)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the below link it works fine. For Further assistance you have to provide code.
    [Populate a tableview using database in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497699/populate-a-tableview-using-database-in-javafx/18634486#18634486)

Answer (score 8):

For some additional info. I was getting the same exception. What I found is that I needed to call the "setCellValueFactory" method when setting up the TableColumn instances. I was mistakenly calling "setCellFactory".

Comment: This fixed the issue for me too. I was mistakenly doing the same thing.

Comment: Just done the same mistake thank you so much for pointing out this typo :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're specifying how to populate the **values** of the column, make sure to use the setCell**Value**Factory method.