# Populate a tableview using database in JavaFX

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview, populate

I'm starting to learn javaFX and I need to populate a table with data from my database. I've read a lot of code online, but I haven't found what I was looking for. I read [this](http://pastebin.com/S0Fg9jK8) but I don't know how to implement that last function. I read some other code to do that and so far this is some of my code:

```
@FXML private TableView<User> table;
@FXML private TableColumn<User, String> nameCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<User, String> emailCol;
private ObservableList<User> data;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory(“name”));
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory(“email”));
    buildData();
}
public void buildData() {
        Connection connect = new Connection();
        Statement st = connect.Connect();
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try {
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER");
             while (rs.next()) {
                ObservableList<User> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                    System.out.println(row);
                }
                data.add(pol);
            }
            tabla.setItems(data);          
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
}
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: Here is a [sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4957967) which [fetches names from a Database into a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878788/javafx-background-thread-for-sql-query).  The concept is similar for populating a TableView from a database.  The [TableView tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) may help, if you have not yet researched it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Items from a Database in a JavaFX TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228502/display-items-from-a-database-in-a-javafx-tableview)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm sure this will help you:

```
public class DBClass{    
     public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{       
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306/dbname","mysqluser","mysqluserpwd"); 
     }
}
```

In Controller Class do the following :

```
@FXML
void initialize(){
     assert tableview != null : "fx:id=\"tableview\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'UserMaster.fxml'.";
     colUserName.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Usermaster,String>("userName"));        
    colPassword.setCellValueFactory(                
        new PropertyValueFactory<Usermaster,String>("userPassword"));
    colUserType.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Usermaster,String>("userType"));        
    colPhoto.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Object,ImageView>("userPhoto"));
    objDbClass = new DBClass();
    try{
        con = objDbClass.getConnection();
        buildData();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
        logger.info(ce.toString());
    }
    catch(SQLException ce){
        logger.info(ce.toString());
    }
}

private ObservableList<Usermaster> data;

public void buildData(){        
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try{      
        String SQL = "Select * from usermaster Order By UserName";            
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);  
        while(rs.next()){
            Usermaster cm = new Usermaster();
            cm.userId.set(rs.getInt("UserId"));                       
            Image img = new Image("tailoring/UserPhoto/User"+cm.getUserId().toString()+".jpg");                

            ImageView mv = new ImageView();
            mv.setImage(img);
            mv.setFitWidth(70);
            mv.setFitHeight(80);
            cm.userPhoto.set(mv);
            cm.userName.set(rs.getString("UserName"));
            cm.userPassword.set(rs.getString("UserPassword"));
            cm.userType.set(rs.getString("UserType"));
            data.add(cm);                  
        }
        tableview.setItems(data);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error on Building Data");            
    }
}
```

and Create a POJO a seperate java file for every entity(table) to want to manipulate using TableView

```
public class Usermaster{    

   public SimpleIntegerProperty userId = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
   public ObjectProperty userPhoto = new SimpleObjectProperty();
   public SimpleStringProperty userName = new SimpleStringProperty(); 
   public SimpleStringProperty userPassword = new SimpleStringProperty();
   public SimpleStringProperty userType = new SimpleStringProperty();
   public SimpleStringProperty encPass = new SimpleStringProperty();
   public SimpleStringProperty updt = new SimpleStringProperty();
   public SimpleStringProperty uptm = new SimpleStringProperty();

   public Integer getUserId() {
      return userId.get();
   }

   public Object getUserPhoto() {
      return userPhoto.get();
   }

   public String getUserName() {
      return userName.get();
   }

   public String getUserPassword() {
      return userPassword.get();
   }

   public String getUserType() {
      return userType.get();
   }

   public String getEncPass() {
      return encPass.get();
   }

   public String getUpdt() {
      return updt.get();
   }

   public String getUptm() {
      return uptm.get();
   }
}
```

I have tested this program it working perfectly.

Comment: Just a note here that this is not a recommended way to create the model class `Usermaster`; having `public` properties is generally a really bad idea. You should make the properties `private` and provide property accessor methods, along with `get` and `set` methods, as in the [examples in the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107)