# load previously inserted table view data in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

In my application table view is working correctly but my problem is when i run the application again I'm not able to get previously inserted data in a table view.it does not load previously inserted data.it show's no content in the table.i need to load previously inserted data every  time while i'm running the application

Comment: Can you show us how are you loading the data in the table and where is the data coming from at start up ?

Comment: Use database and connect to your table insert data to database

Comment: Ref this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497699/populate-a-tableview-using-database-in-javafx