# java.lang.ClassCastException when Populating TableView with Data class

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, classcastexception

I have created a tableview in my view.fxml which refers to `table`(TableView variable) in my controller class. `showFilesTableView()` is call in the `initialize()` method.

```
public void showFilesTableView() {

     TableColumn Name = new TableColumn<AllInfo,String>("Name");
    Name.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AllInfo, String>("name"));
    table.getColumns().add(Name);

    TableColumn Size = new TableColumn<AllInfo,String>("Size");
    Size.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AllInfo, String>("size"));
    table.getColumns().add(Size);

    TableColumn dmd = new TableColumn<AllInfo,String>("Date Modified");
    dmd.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AllInfo, String>("date"));
    table.getColumns().add(dmd);

    ObservableList<AllInfo>  data= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    File[] files = (new File(textfield.getText())).listFiles();

    for(File f: files) {

        AllInfo obj = new AllInfo();
        obj.name.set(f.getName());
        obj.size.set(String.valueOf(f.length()));
        obj.date.set(String.valueOf(f.lastModified()));

        data.add(obj);

    }
    table.setItems(data);
}
```

The AllInfo class is:

```
public class AllInfo {

    public SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty size = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty date = new SimpleStringProperty();
}
```

But this error is showing all the time....

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures
```

Full error:

```
    Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellDataFeatures
    at javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:98)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.getCell(TableRowSkin.java:87)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.getCell(TableRowSkin.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.createCell(TableRowSkinBase.java:698)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.recreateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:692)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:872)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9056)
    at javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9153)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1964)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1797)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1879)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2528)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1189)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1646)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1720)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:846)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:922)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:937)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497699/populate-a-tableview-using-database-in-javafx/18634486#18634486) but still the errors are occuring.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `PropertyValueFactory`s as `cellFactory`s instead of `cellValueFactory`s.

Since you're using raw types, the compiler cannot check, if the type parameters of `Callback` are correct, which would have caused a compile time error.

Simply replace `setCellFactory` with `setCellValueFactory` in your code to fix this issue:

```
Size.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AllInfo, String>("size"));
...
```

and better add the type parameters to the `TableColumn` declarations:

```
TableColumn<AllInfo, String> Size = ...
...
```

Furthermore fields being contained in the item class is insufficient to make the data show up. `PropertyValueFactory` looks for methods returning the property `nameProperty()`, `sizeProperty` and `dateProperty` in this case.